# Cannot extract artifact from azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, artifact

I have a problem with extracting artifacts.
I have a task to download artifact from pipeline, once done it should extract zip file but it's throwing an error : Error: Failed rmRF: Command failed: rd /s /q "c:\Users\agent_002\xxx"
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I tried to check if I copy this file into another location and then try to unzip it but without any luck.
Any ideas what process can use that and how to fix this ?

my code:

```yaml
 - stage: download_and_extract
  jobs:
  - job: download_pipeline_artefact
    pool:
      name: default
      demands: agent.os -equals Windows_NT

    steps:
    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      inputs:       
        patterns: '**/*.zip'
        path: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/bin

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs: 
        sourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/bin/
        targetFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

    - task: ExtractFiles@1
      inputs:
        archiveFilePatterns: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/xxx/xxx.zip'
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference. I did a workaround and used powershell script to extract the file. It completed successfully.